# implicit conversion of Object to XML in flex 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, apache-flex, actionscript-3, date

when I send an object through an HTTPService to an XML api run by a Rest ruby on rails server.. how does it get converted to XML? I mean, it just works fine for strings and numbers, but for example Date type conversion causes an "unprocessable entity" error on rails log..

Any Idea?

Comment: It's possible that I misunderstood your question. Is your Ruby on Rails server receiving the XML or sending it?

Comment: Yes it's receiving the XML, anyway I've solved the problem, if not elegantly...

Comment: Do you mind posting your solution here so we can review it?

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is that when the object is converted to XML, Flash calls `toString()` on the Date object, resulting in the `Day Mon DD HH:MM:SS TZD YYYY` format. If you call `valueOf()` on the Date object, you will get milliseconds since epoch, which is probably better for your case.

Comment: probably.. but it'd be nice to know..
anyway I wrote a function to parse every Data field and convert it to the proper string format..

Answer (score 0):

How to convert as3 objects to xml

http://blog.flexexamples.com/2008/03/04/converting-objects-to-xml-packets-using-the-simplexmlencoder-class-in-flex/